Only colour part of axis in matplotlib
Consider the simple plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0.9, 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3]
y = [0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 1]

plt.plot(x,y)

plt.margins(x=0, y=0)
plt.xlim(0,3)

This generates a line plot. From here I would like to colour part of my x-axis such that from 0 to 0.9 is blue and from 0.9 to 3  is red. One solution I came up with is include two more line plots: plt.plot([0,0.9], [0,0], color = "b" ,linewidth=3.0) and
plt.plot([0.9,3.0], [0,0], color = "r",linewidth=3.0). Giving the following picture:

This looks okay, but I'm not entirely happy with it. To me it is clear that those lines are not on the axis, but rather slightly above the axis. Instead I would prefer to have the axis + ticks take on the respective colour.

You could use a variation of the method described here to replace the x-axis with a custom segmented line and manually change the ticklabels/ticklines colors:
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

ax = plt.gca()

colors = ['b', 'r']
x = [0, .9, 3]
y = [0, 0, 0]
points = np.c_[x, y][:, None]
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)
lc = LineCollection(segments,colors=colors, linewidth=2,
                    transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform(),
                    clip_on=False)
ax.add_collection(lc)

ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)

for t in ax.get_xticklabels():
    t.set_color(colors[int(t.get_position()[0] > 0.9)])

Output:

Variation with numpy.searchsorted to handle more than 2 colors (use 'left'/'right' to change how a tick at a boundary associates to the previous/next segment):
colors = ['b', 'r', 'g']
x = [0, .9, 2, 3]
y = [0]*len(x)

# [...]

colors_ = np.array(colors)[np.clip(np.searchsorted(x, ax.get_xticks(),
                                                   'left')-1,
                                   0, len(colors)-1)]

for c, t, l in zip(colors_,
                   ax.get_xticklabels(),
                   ax.get_xticklines()[::2]):
    t.set_color(c)
    l.set_markeredgecolor(c)

Output (left/right ; note the color of 2.0):


